# Centering label in a frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having trouble trying to center a label inside a frame. I'm using the grid geometry manager and I've tried all sorts of things such as using 'sticky' and re-arranging the way my frame works. Heres a screenshot of what it looks like now:

[image: example]

I'm trying to get the 'even' text to be centered in the frame. Here is my current code:

```
the_frame = Frame(the_window, width= 400, height = 150,
                  relief = 'groove', borderwidth = 2)
the_frame.grid_propagate(False)
the_text = Label(the_frame, text = 'Even')
alpha_check = Checkbutton(the_window, text = 'Alpha', variable = boxtick0,
                          command = oddoreven)
beta_check = Checkbutton(the_window, text = 'Beta', variable = boxtick1,
                          command = oddoreven)
gamma_check = Checkbutton(the_window, text = 'Gamma', variable = boxtick2,
                          command = oddoreven)
margin = 5
the_frame.grid(padx = margin, pady = margin,
                row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 3)
the_text.grid(padx = margin, pady = margin, row = 2,
                column = 2, sticky=W+E+N+S)
alpha_check.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 2, column = 1)
beta_check.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 2, column = 2)
gamma_check.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 2, column = 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't assigning any weights to your rows and columns. That causes rows and columns to be just big enough to hold their contents. If there is extra room in the GUI, it will go unallocated. In your case, the column that contains the label will only be exactly wide enough to fit the label, and all the space to the right goes unused.

You can give column zero and row zero a positive weight to instruct `grid` to give extra space to that row and column like this:

```
the_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
the_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

ALso, you're putting the label at row one, column one, but row and column numbering start at zero. It's harmless since rows and columns that don't contain anything will take up no space (unless you give them weight).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! Using the .place method works since the_text is a child of the parent object the_frame. Here's what I did:

```
the_text.place(relx= 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = CENTER)
```